# Cannot add addon by URL - Microsoft 365 Admin Centre

Tags: microsoft-365

#### Summary

A customer is trying to add an integrated custom app (add-in) and receiving an error after inputting the "custom url".

#### Replication steps

1. Login to https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal
2. Select … Show All then Settings > Integrated apps
3. Click Add-ins on the top right
4. In the new window, click Deploy add-ins
5. Click next then upload custom app
6. Select upload manifest from URL and enter the manifest.xml address and click 'next'

**Result** - Following error displayed

> Cannot perform the action you requested. Please try again later.
> (510c4e02-b030-40ed-9992-2ae8832bdabf)

**Things I checked/tried**

- Generic error makes google search diluted.
- The error code in the message changes every time we re-try it, so unsure of it's meaning.
- The user can visit the xml url in their browser (i.e. not blocked by proxy)
- The user has the "Global Admin" role assigned in the user admin center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url needs to contain the protocol `https://`

Despite it already being embedded in front of the input field.

**The below is the correct example of how to input this field.**

[image]